# Can't edit content in textarea using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Content shows just fine in the textarea but it doesn't seem to be editable.

I created a simplified version of the problem I'm having below.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="WeekController">
    <form>
        <textarea ng-model="currentDay.content"></textarea>
    </form>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var stories = angular.module('stories', []);

stories.controller('WeekController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.currentDay = {
        content: "Tenetur perspiciatis ut maiores et corrupti aut."
    };
});
```

How can I fix that and why is it happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have ng-app defined somewhere, like in your <html /> tag?

Comment: Its working correctly <a class="jsbin-embed" href="http://jsbin.com/lujicicirovo/1/embed?html,js,output">JS Bin</a>

Comment: It turned out to be unrelated code that caught all input while inside textarea. Thanks (not sure what to do with this question now as it's pointless - unrelated to angular.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
<html ng-app="stories">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.0-beta.5" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
      var stories = angular.module('stories', []);

      stories.controller('WeekController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.currentDay = {
            content: "Tenetur perspiciatis ut maiores et corrupti aut."
        };
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="WeekController">
      <form>
          <textarea ng-model="currentDay.content"></textarea>
      </form>

      Value of currentDay: 
      <code>
        {{ currentDay | json }}
      </code>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

See this live at http://plnkr.co/edit/Zf6FRgPON7wO5TmezTsS?p=preview

... unless I'm mis-understanding what you're saying doesn't work. The textarea is editable and does update the $scope variable.